# Event listener(s) to intercept incoming requests and outgoing responses?

Tags: jetty, jetty-12

I'd like to log all incoming requests and outgoing responses coming into or going out of my server.

Is there an event listener that I can register that will provide a `Request` object before it is passed to any `Handler` and a `Response` object before it is sent out?

I already manually inserted log statements everywhere I could find, but some calls never reach my application's `Handler`. For example, if a user invokes `HTTP GET https://example.com//quests/195` I get:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Ambiguous URI empty segment
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection$HttpStreamOverHTTP1.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseFields(HttpParser.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.parseRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io@12.0.0/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314)
```

In the above case, I have no where to get at a `Request` object so I can log the incoming request, nor the response that gets sent out automatically by Jetty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

**Choice 1: Create a custom Handler.Wrapper with custom Request.Wrapper and Response.Wrapper**

Create a normal Handler.Wrapper, and put it somewhere early in your Handler tree.

Then you can just wrap the existing request/response with your own implementation and pass it into the wrapped handler.

Eg:

```java
public class CustomRequestResponseHandler extends Handler.Wrapper
{
    @Override
    public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception
    {
        Request.Wrapper myRequest = new Request.Wrapper(request)
        {
            @Override
            public HttpURI getHttpURI()
            {
                // TODO: give a different URI? or perhaps just log the URI used?
                return super.getHttpURI();
            }
        };

        Response.Wrapper myResponse = new Response.Wrapper(request, response)
        {
            @Override
            public void write(boolean last, ByteBuffer byteBuffer, Callback callback)
            {
                // TODO: do something with the write
                super.write(last, byteBuffer, callback);
            }
        };

        return super.handle(myRequest, myResponse, callback);
    }
}
```

**Choice 2: Create your EventsHandler to capture events**

The abstract `EventsHandler` has a few events that you can hook into at different points during the handling that might be useful for you.

```java
public static class CustomEventsHandler extends EventsHandler
{
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeHandling(Request request) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRequestRead(Request request, Content.Chunk chunk) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAfterHandling(Request request, boolean handled, Throwable failure) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseBegin(Request request, int status, HttpFields headers) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseWrite(Request request, boolean last, ByteBuffer content) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseWriteComplete(Request request, Throwable failure) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResponseTrailersComplete(Request request, HttpFields trailers) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComplete(Request request, Throwable failure) {
    }
}
```

See

- [Source to EventsHandler in Jetty 12.0.3](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-12.0.3/jetty-core/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/EventsHandler.java)
- [Javadoc of EventsHandler](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/EventsHandler.html)